# What is the syntax for Dates in MongoDB running on MongoLab?

Tags: json, mongodb, datetime, bson, mlab

Instead of ObjectId('82he921he982he82') its "_id":{"$oid":"82he921he982he82"} for object Ids, but I have no idea how to create a date value in a document on MongoLab :s

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you are using one of the drivers, you create a date via that language's Date class. For instance, in Javascript (like Node.js) it would be 'new Date(11,11,11)'. If using the MongoLab REST API or admin UI you represent dates with this syntax:

```
  { "$date": "2010-10-28T23:07:11Z" }
```

Comment: Thanks! I should have known it was that simple :p

Answer (score 5):

Also if an item has:

```
"dateAdded": {
   "$date": "2012-07-30T15:26:15.321Z"
}
```

in one of it's entries, then you can find it by searching:

```
{
    "dateAdded": {
        "$gt": {
            "$date": "2012-07-28T23:07:11Z"
        }
    }
}
```