# MongoDB DateTime Format

Tags: mongodb

In mongodb adhoc query, before executing the query, how to format the date type element to `dd\mm\yyyy` format and then execute the query?

Comment: um, what programming language are you using? Are you doing this programmatically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved this by inserting the datetime as integer using the getTime() method in java.
EG:

```
Date dt=new Date();
long integer_date=dt.getTime();
```

I used the above line of code to insert date as integer.With this it was easy to fetch records between a particular date.

Answer (score 2):

I asked a similar question a little while back...this might be what you're looking for: [What is the syntax for Dates in MongoDB running on MongoLab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8005670/what-is-the-syntax-for-dates-in-mongodb-running-on-mongolab)

Comment: I read through your answer.. actually am using a java driver and i use the syntax new Date() to insert the current date.Now i have to fetch records within the given range.The problem is the date in the mongodb is in dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss format now the one which i get to fetch record is of format dd/MM/yyyy so i am not able to fetch the records properls.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Java, you can create Date objects from strings using the parse method of the DateFormat class.

The Java documentation on the DateFormat Class may be found here:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html

The specific section on the parse method is here:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#parse%28java.lang.String%29

The Java documentation on the Date object may be found here:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Date.html
As per the "Constructor Summary" section, the ability to pass a string into the constructor is "Deprecated. As of JDK version 1.1, replaced by DateFormat.parse(String s)."

While I was researching the above, I also came across the Calendar class, which may be used for converting a Date object and a set of integers.  It may not be necessary for this application, but I thought it might be useful to include a link to the documentation: 
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html

Integers for year, month, day, hour, etcetera may be passed in via the set method:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#set%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29

By way of example, here is a short Java Program that creates a number of Date objects, stores them in a Mongo collection, and then executes a query similar to what you have described.  Hopefully it will help you to accomplish your goal.  NOTE: This program drops a collection named "dates", so be sure to change the collection name if you already have such a collection in your database!

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws UnknownHostException, MongoException {
    Mongo m = new Mongo( "localhost:27017" );
    DB db = m.getDB("test");

    DBCollection coll = db.getCollection("dates");
    coll.drop();

    DateFormat df = DateFormat.getInstance();
    String dateString = new String();
    Date myDate = new Date();
    // Save some test documents
    for(int i=1; i<11; i++){
        dateString = "04/" + String.valueOf(i) + "/12 11:00 AM, EST";
        BasicDBObject myObj = new BasicDBObject("_id", i);
        try {
            myDate = df.parse(dateString);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        myObj.put("date", myDate);
        System.out.println(myDate);
        coll.save(myObj);
    }

    // Build the query 
    Date startDate = new Date();
    Date endDate = new Date();
    try {
        startDate = df.parse("04/4/12 11:00 AM, EST");
        endDate = df.parse("04/6/12 11:00 AM, EST");
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    BasicDBObject dateQuery = new BasicDBObject();
    dateQuery.put("$gte", startDate);
    dateQuery.put("$lte", endDate);

    System.out.println("---------------");
    //Execute the query
    DBCursor myCursor  = coll.find(new BasicDBObject("date", dateQuery));

    //Print the results
    while(myCursor.hasNext()){
        System.out.println(myCursor.next().toString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is use full to format code to date format from simple date time format and the reverse steps also supporting this way to retrieve date from MongoDB.

```
  SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
  Date fDate = formatter.parse((String) metaData.getValue());
  newMeta.setValue(fDate);[![In this image you can see how is the save scenario process in mongoDB][1]][1]
```

Answer (score 0):

`Date` class has a `before(date)` or `after(date)` method... It is easy to use: no conversion to seconds/milliseconds.

```
public void execute(Tuple input) {
    try {
        date=(Date) input.getValueByField("date");
        boolean before = date.before(myDate); // compare the data retrieved with your date.
        if (before) {
            ...
        } else {
            ...
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("Error...", e);
    }
```

This approach is easier than the accepted answer..