# Inserting DateTime into MongoDB

Tags: c#, mongodb, datetime, insert

Is there something which I need to take into consideration when Im trying to serialize data into Mongo database which is keyed by DateTime?

My data looks like this `SortedDictionary<DateTime, Data> Data` and the problem Im facing is that the DateTime key have time part equal to `00:00:00` but after insertion into Mongo it is `ISODate("2003-11-24T23:00:00Z")` sometimes `T22:00:00Z`.
I preaty sure the problem is not with data Im inserting into DB I checked on every possible place if time part is always equal to `00:00:00` and it is.

Comment: It sounds like localisation settings in C# doing this, but I am not a C# expert, I haven't programmed it in years

Answer (score 0):

mongo stores dates in UTC format by default so it seems you are in different time zone hence the difference

Comment: What would be the best approach to solve this? Should I look into time zone settings of mongo or should I rather fix my code somehow?

Answer (score 0):

Are you converting from a string to a datatime in C#? Maybe that is causing it to be off by an hour because of daylight savings, local time, or UTC.

The C# mongodb driver handles the format.  You could quickly test using something like an integer to be sure it's not your format prior to insertion. [MongoDB DateTime Format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9944694/mongodb-datetime-format)

Comment: I run a little test I created simple object with only one DateTime property assigned it value of `DateTime.Now.Date` inserted into Mongo and result is still `ISODate("2014-06-24T22:00:00Z")`

Comment: I dont think it's on the MongoDB side.  It sounds like it's on the C# side with how you are arriving at the dateTime object.  You are probably thinking you are setting it to 00:00 but the time zone or daylight savings is actually making it off by an hour or two.

Comment: Im setting it to `00:00` I can see it in debbuger. So problem is in time zones do you know how to solve this because I have no idea. Working with dates is always a trouble.

Comment: Try `DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal` in your parsing code, or parse the string and then call the `DateTimeOffset.ToUniversalTime` method of the returned `DateTimeOffset` object.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb504692(v=vs.110).aspx