# Convert ISODate() field to MySQL datetime format

Tags: datetime, mongodb-query, isodate

I have a MongoDB that includes a data field in `ISODate` format.  One record, for example, could be `ISODate("2013-11-16T00:00:00Z")`

Now I need to convert this to MySQL `datetime` format through Mongo Shell.

How can I use Mongo Shell to convert that value to a MySQL `datetime` format, `2013-11-16 00:00:00` in this case?

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will helps you

[MongoDB DateTime Format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9944694/mongodb-datetime-format)

Comment: I had similar problem, I do not see any great help in the above link

Comment: {"_id" : ObjectId("5e2d6c805e66af2cef0371ab"), "vendorType" : "MRC", "created_at" : ISODate("2020-01-26T10:40:00.514Z")} In this I just want to remove ISOdate and open and close braces

I want something look like this:
{
    "_id" : "5e2d6c805e66af2cef0371ab",
    "vendorType" : "MRC",
    "created_at" : "2020-01-26T10:40:00.514Z",
    "__v" : 0
}`